# SQL 2005 Report Designer - Using specific table cells as data in charts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, report-designer

I have various reports built in MS SQL 2005 Report Designer, displaying various sums and counts of different data. Now I need to implement different types of charts in these reports (Bar graphs, Pie charts), using the data from the summed cells (subtotals and grand totals for groups).

I don't see any ways to specify a table cell as input for a chart's data in the chart properties, it gives me errors saying it's not part of the "data region." I can't find any info on how to create data regions, and I assume I don't want to use "data output" because that only deals with exporting xml?

Can anyone give me some direction on how to easily link table group subtotals to chart input data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Different report items (tables, chart, etc) don't have to derive from the one dataset. Just use different datasets for the different report items. Let's say your main report table uses a dataset that shows the invoices sent by different branches, which you sum at the branch level:

```
SELECT Branch, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, InvoiceAmount
FROM Invoices
ORDER BY Branch, InvoiceNumber
```

Simply create another dataset for the pie chart being the summary information:

```
SELECT Branch, SUM(InvoiceAmount) AS BranchSum
FROM Invoices
GROUP BY Branch
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Report Designer only lets you have one query to build the dataset though, how am I supposed to select the same attribute twice in the same query for two different datasets? Also I was half asking about the syntax for stating values in the chart data, is it just the normal Fields!Name.Value? Where is the different dataset denotated in that notation?

Answer (score 0):

you want to create a expression calling on the dataset

=Sum(Fields!InvoiceAmount.value, "DataSet1")

If you want to call on the same Field just use AS in the select statement.

Select 
    Invoices.InvoiceAmount AS InvoiceAmt

InvoiceAmt will then be a useable field equal to invoiceamount